# few bugs in pro asp.net mvc 3 book from aPress

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I'm reading this book and I no matter what I try I cannot make this example run properly as it uses ninject I have never even heard of before I would appreciate if someone could help me get it running

Author(s) of this book says that I should add new folder (infrastructure) and add new .cs file  (NinjectControllerFactory) to project and then add following code to it

```
private IKernel ninjectKernel;
public NinjectControllerFactory()
{
    ninjectKernel = new StandardKernel();
    AddBindings();
}

//problem with override
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
{
    return controllerType == null
        ? null
        : (IController) ninjectKernel.Get(controllerType);
}
```

If I try to debug it I have a problem as VS says that I cannot override that method. I have simply removed override and tried to run it again but once again I have a problem with this line of code:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
```

I had to add it `global.aspx` -> `Application_Start()` method but I have a problem as VS says that I have to cast it to `IControllerFactory` so i have modified it to

```
ControllerBuilder.Current
    .SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory() as IControllerFactory);
```

but now I get `ArgumentNullException` on that line.

Anyone know how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Do they not tell you which class or interface to inherit the factory from?

Comment: yeo you are right I forgot to inherit DefaultControllerFactory, thx

Comment: If you are in fact using ASP.NET MVC 3, you should be using the DependencyResolver instead of creating your own controller factory. It's kind of surprising that the book still advises using the old MVC2 approach. See here for DependencyResolver with Ninject: http://blog.decayingcode.com/post/2011/02/11/Using-Ninject-with-ASPNET-MVC-3-dependency-injection.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either want to

1. inherit your class from [System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory.aspx) which includes GetControllerInstance to override
2. get hold of [ninject.web.mvc](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc) which [already implements NinjectControllerFactory](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc2/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/NinjectControllerFactory.cs) for you
    (although it looks like they use a different mechanism for MVC3?)